# MySQL LOAD_FILE function return 0x -- why? (macOS)

Tags: mysql

I lost a considerable amount of time on this one.

I'm attempting to load some .lob file to a column in my database but can't make it work. I've tried to isolate the problem but can't find it. Granted, I'm not the expert on MySQL and hope you guys can help me.

Here's my dump file config (/usr/local/etc/my.cnf )

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
innodb_file_per_table
max_allowed_packet=32M
secure_file_priv = ''
```

I set "secure_file_priv" to an empty quote since it was always returning NULL before. The I granted client/server permission:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile=1
```

Then restart the MySQL service and tried to upload a single file with this command/result:

```
mysql> SELECT LOAD_FILE('~/Desktop/mysqltest.txt') AS Result;
+----------------+
| Result         |
+----------------+
| 0x             |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think the result is not normal? Why it returns "0x" instead of the text inside the file?

I also tried with my complete SQL script:

```
Truncate Table capublic.law_section_tbl;
LOAD DATA LOCAL
  INFILE "LAW_SECTION_TBL.dat"
  INTO TABLE capublic.law_section_tbl
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '`'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(
   ID
  ,LAW_CODE
  ,SECTION_NUM
  ,OP_STATUES
  ,OP_CHAPTER
  ,OP_SECTION
  ,EFFECTIVE_DATE
  ,LAW_SECTION_VERSION_ID
  ,DIVISION
  ,TITLE
  ,PART
  ,CHAPTER
  ,ARTICLE
  ,HISTORY
  ,@var1
  ,ACTIVE_FLG
  ,TRANS_UID
  ,TRANS_UPDATE
)
SET CONTENT_XML=LOAD_FILE(concat('/Users/dominicbouchard/Desktop/pubinfo_1/pubinfo/'),@var1)
```

without success. The terminal gives me this result:

```
Username@MacBook-Pro pubinfo % ./loadData.sh
Please enter root password: ******
Processing table: bill_version_tbl
Processing table: codes_tbl
Processing table: committee_hearing_tbl
Processing table: daily_file_tbl
Processing table: law_section_tbl
Processing table: law_toc_sections_tbl
Processing table: law_toc_tbl
Processing table: legislator_tbl
Processing table: location_code_tbl
Processing table: veto_message_tbl
Processing table: committee_agenda_tbl
```

But no files are actually uploaded and it still shows NULL in my 'content_xml' column Any clue whats going on??  Thanks!

(post edited)

Comment: "ERROR 1582 (42000) at line 2: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'LOAD_FILE'" is because `),@var1)` should be `,@var1))`

Comment: Dang! Yeah, it fixed the error. Thanks! But still, the LOAD_FILE command doesn't work :( The value in the column return NULL...